# Pytest works with old mock, but not unittest.mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I'm porting some code from Python 2 to 3, and `py.test` isn't playing well with the `patch` decorator from `unittest.mock`. When I use the `patch` decorator to pass a mock into the arguments of a test function, `py.test` instead interprets that argument to be a fixture, and is unable to set up the test.

Here's a contrived example that hopefully illuminates the problem:

```
@patch('my_module.my_func')
def test_my_func(mock_func):
    mock_func()
    mock_func.assert_called_once_with()
```

After running `py.test`, the error message would look like:

```
E       fixture 'my_func' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capsys, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

This is the only scenario under which this failure occurs. If I explicitly call the test (i.e. run `test_my_func()`), no error. If I patch `my_func` using either of the other patching techniques, no error. If I import patch from `mock` instead of `unittest.mock`, no error.

It's only while running my tests using `py.test`, using `unittest.mock`, and patching using the decorator when this occurs.

I'm running Python 3.4.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, mock decorators are not supported.
It's not such bad -- changing function signature by decorator appliance is considered as bad idea.
But you still  may use `with mock.patch(...)` syntax.

Also as an option there is [pytest-mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-mock) plugin with pretty clean api for mocking:

```
def test_foo(mocker):
    # all valid calls
    mocker.patch('os.remove')
    mocker.patch.object(os, 'listdir', autospec=True)
    mocked_isfile = mocker.patch('os.path.isfile')
```

Comment: when you say that they are not supported, who doesnt support them? see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html, it mentions patch's usability as a decorator

Comment: also, using the newer unittest.mock.patch(), you can get the mock from @patch if you use test_my_func(*args). Your mock will be in args[0]

Comment: Mock decorators were not compatible with `pytest` until pytest 3.4.1. Please note: `pytest` is not the same as the standard `unittest` library.

Answer (score 4):

There was a `pytest` issue that now seems to be solved in a newer version of `pytest`:
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/3206/commits/b6166dccb4d2b48173aa7e7739be52db9d2d56a0

Basically, if you had `mock` installed, this would fail. You can verify by uninstalling `mock` and running the test again.

If you really need that version of pytest, you can get the mock using `with patch(..)` inside the function.