# Mocking Django inclusion tag in pytest

Tags: django, pytest

I have an inclusion tag:

```
from django import template
from accounts.models import UserTracking
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True) 
def has_shipped(context):
    return UserTracking.objects.filter(shipping=True, user=context['request'].user).exists()
```

and I am testing a function, `awarded`, that is calling a template that contains that tag.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from myproject.views import awarded

@patch('myproject.templatetags.something.has_shipped')
def test_awarded(mymock, rf):
    mymock.return_value = ''   # this is not having any effect
    result = awarded(rf)
    assert result
```

and the code under test:

```
def awarded(request):
    return render(request, 'awarded_form.html', {'revisions' : revisions})
```

Pytest is yelling at me because it says I'm using the database, which I am (but don't want to), so I want to mock the function containing the database call, `has_shipped`.  How do I do that?  When I try to mock the function directly from where it is declared, it doesn't work, because it's apparently not the right scope, so how do I do this?  And is this one of those situations where it's just easier to throw `@mark_db` on it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169563/pytest-works-with-old-mock-but-not-unittest-mock

Comment: @Md.NahidurRahman that question has to do with patch not working at all.  My question is specifically asking about mocking/patching a Django inclusion tag.